# Add custom attributes when creating product via REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, custom-attributes, create-product

I am attempting to set custom attributes when creating a new product via the REST API. The products have a required attribute `hpUuid`. This is part of my JSON file to create the new product:

```
{
    "product": {
        "sku": "12345",

        ... Quite a few fields here ...

        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "hpUuid",
                "value": "123"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

When submitting, the REST API returns this error:

```
{"message":"The \"hpUuid\" attribute value is empty. Set the attribute and try again."}
```

[The fine docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/create-configurable-product.html) suggest that the format is correct, but **why can it not read the value**?

**EDIT:** More information

I have tried two similar request bodies, based on different examples that I have found. One based on the fine manual is here:

```
{
    "product": {
        "name": "My Fine Product",
        "sku": "123",
        "attribute_set_id": 4,
        "status": 1,
        "visibility": 4,
        "type_id": "configurable",
        "extension_attributes": {
            "category_links": [
                {
                    "position": 0,
                    "category_id": "2"
                }
            ]
        },
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "hpUuid",
                "value": "52"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And another based on an accepted Stack Overflow answer is here:

```
{
    "product": {
        "sku": "sku_from_rest",
        "name": "My Fine Product",
        "attribute_set_id": "4",
        "status": 1,
        "visibility": 4,
        "type_id": "virtual",
        "weight": 0,
        "extension_attributes": {
            "stock_item": {
                "stock_id": 1,
                "qty": 20,
                "is_in_stock": true,
                "is_qty_decimal": false,
                "use_config_min_qty": true,
                "min_qty": 0,
                "use_config_min_sale_qty": 0,
                "min_sale_qty": 0,
                "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
                "max_sale_qty": 0,
                "use_config_backorders": false,
                "backorders": 0,
                "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
                "notify_stock_qty": 20,
                "use_config_qty_increments": false,
                "qty_increments": 0,
                "use_config_enable_qty_inc": false,
                "enable_qty_increments": false,
                "use_config_manage_stock": true,
                "manage_stock": true,
                "low_stock_date": "string",
                "is_decimal_divided": true,
                "stock_status_changed_auto": 0,
                "extension_attributes": {}
            }
        },
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "hpUuid",
                "value": "123"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have ensured that the `attribute_set_id` value of `4` is correct for the default attribute set. I have addionally added an attribute set number `9` which is a clone of the Default set. However, when I use the `attribute_set_id` value of `9` the product is created without an `hpUuid`, as if the value that I submitted was simply ignored.

Comment: Could you please put the exact request body you are using

Comment: @vitoriodachef: Thank you, I have added the excact request bodies that I have tried.

Comment: @dotancohen Did you solve this?

Comment: @Kilise: No, I never resolved this issue. I went on to code other parts of the system and then the whole project was indefinitely shelved.

Comment: you can't create an attribute during creating the product. you have to create the attribute before the product using the '/rest/V1/products/attributes' endpoint, and after that you have to assign them to an attribute set. i dont know how to do this, if you find out, please reply me

Comment: @kexx: Thank you. The `hpUuid` does in fact exist, it was created in the admin panel. But that is an excellent point.

Comment: @dotancohen maybe there is one thing to try. by the name of the field i assume it is something numerical, like decimal. there is no number kind attribute in magento, but some of the have the "backend_type": "decimal". So trying to send it as a number instead of a string in the JSON maybe worth a shot

Comment: Actually the field was a "plain text" or string field.

Comment: I am having the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @webrain No, this issue was never resolved.